# Authentication unsuccessful error even after right username and password passing in "HTTP Authorization Manager"

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

```
HTTP/1.1 401 
X-message-code: PWD_WRONG
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="SAP HANA Cloud Platform"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 18 Oct 2019 11:06:40 GMT
Server: SAP
Set-Cookie: BIGipServerl4097iflmapavrhcip.factory.customdomain=!Nu8jU3HA2IxyvHz2sXeD7QV2Vba36noiDcfL3aW4P6aJ3bFLqxzKN/NcLEGyHmjUFAx3qBE6h10zBwU=; path=/; Httponly; Secure; httponly; secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
```

Comment: You can use , So first you need to know about [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) and then Basic Authentication in JMeter [Here](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

Some times, the site may encode the password at the frontend and then send it to the server which can decode it. Check with your dev team if the password is encoded by a javascript before being sent

Answer (score 0):

1. Logically `X-message-code: PWD_WRONG` indicates that you provided wrong password. Double check your credentials in the HTTP Authorization Manager, it might be the case you made a typo, even characters which are not visible like [whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) or [line break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) matter.
2. Looking into [Create new user on Cloud Integration](https://answers.sap.com/questions/389003/create-new-user-on-cloud-integration.html) thread:

   > The message displayed (PWD_WRONG) means the member has never logged into the SCP Account and no credentials were provided to it.
3. Also looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694429/curl-with-client-certificate-authentication) it might be the case you need to supply an appropriate [client-side certificate](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates/)